# How to check if an input value is exists and validate if yes in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I made a text input filed with jquery autocomplete where I query the users. So if I start typing the name of a user it shows the related users. It works fine but I like to avoid
that if the user like not to choose from the pupped up list and possibly type all the name and it has a mistake.
So I like to make a function that checks if the added value of the field is equals with any of the users in the database. How to do that?

**html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type name here" name="kap_bar_01" id="kap_bar_01"> 

<script>
     $(function() {
        var names  =  [

          {% for u in related_users %}
            "{{ u.user.last_name }} {{ u.user.first_name }}",
          {% endfor %}
        ];

        $( "#kap_bar_01" ).autocomplete({
           source: names
        });
     });
  </script>
```

**models.py**

```
class Kapcsolodasok(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)

    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    kap_bar_01 = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
def kapcsolodasok(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    related_users = Profile.objects.filter(projekt=profile.projekt)

    context = {
        'related_users': related_users,
        'profile': profile,
    }

    #lots of stuffs here

    return render(request, 'stressz/kapcsolodasok.html', context)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `names.indexOf('inputted_value')` to check if the name is in the array.  The best place to put this would be when the user clicks to send the form.  It's hard to answer more specifically without your full html, or at least the whole form section.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
userList = User.objects.values()
```

The above code will get the usernames as list and loopover to check the username entered.But i think you want it to be checked in realtime so you have to use channels or ajax etc.Otherwise just pass the username value as url url/ and check it